# What is the true maximum values for AWS quotas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Does anywhere officially or unofficially document what the true maximums are for all AWS quotas?**

I am new to AWS, and am trying to figure out the maximum values for certain quotas.

For example, the default value for [S3 Access Points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-restrictions-limitations.html) supports a maximum of 1000 per account.

but in [the AWS quota console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services) it says it is `Adjustable`, and [the docs suggest I can request a quota increase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-restrictions-limitations.html).

> You can create a maximum of 1,000 access points per AWS account per Region. If you need more than 1,000 access points for a single account in a single Region, you can request a service quota increase. For more information about service quotas and requesting an increase, see AWS Service Quotas in the AWS General Reference.

I'd like to know what the true maximums are across the board for IAM and S3 resources, to ease design of features I'm working on, without having to do a request to increase resources I may not actually use, if appropriate resource limits can't be requested.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with AWS support, some quota changes aren't reflected in this console at this time (e.g dynamoDb quota changes)

Haven't tried it, but possibly using [aws-limit-checker](https://github.com/jantman/awslimitchecker) may show the real limits